# How to enter the next digest circle in a function of angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, timeout

I am trying to refresh a google map which is hidden when app inits. I want to show it and refresh it by clicking a button.

However, when put an `alert()` before the map refreshing, **it works well**:

```
function showAndRefreshMap() 
{
    showMapDiv();
    alert(0);
    $scope.map.refresh();
}
```

But if I user `$timeout` or `$interval`, **a type error appears**:

```
function showAndRefreshMap() 
{
    showMapDiv();
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.map.refresh();
    },500);
}
```

I get the following error

> TypeError: $scope.map.control.refresh is not a function

Thus, I am wondering if using `$timeout` or `$interval` can cause **another digest circle** in angularjs.

How can I come into next digest circle in angularjs? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your second code snippet doesn't match the first.  You're incorrectly trying to traverse into the control property. You should instead call it in the same manner you're calling the first function.

```
function showAndRefreshMap() {
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.map.refresh({latitude:80, longitude: -2});
    },500);
}
```

Comment: Great thanks for your answer. Before I post my question, I have tried your answer, it did not work for me.

Comment: I guarantee that my answer will change the error message or behavior that you get.  What happens after you make that change?  Do you receive another error?  Your question edit doesn't match your error.

Comment: The same error, TypeError: $scope.map.control.refresh is not a function

Comment: If you're getting the same error then you didn't change your code.  Please create a CONSISTENT reproduction of your issue in JSFiddle or Plunkr since what you've described simply doesn't match your error.